Can't install or compile mingw tools on Arch Linux (EndeavourOS)
While trying to install proton for my laptop, I ran across a problem where the package mingw-w64-tools would always fail with an exit code of 4.
After trying a few more times, I ended up attempting to build from source, which proved to be useless, as unless I ran the ./configure file with 'sh' (I use zsh as my main shell) the command would return "permission denied". However, even running both the ./configure file for the entire package as well as the PKGBUILD I received from the AUR for the tools package, I always got an unclear error and the program crashed. For the ./configure file, the error was usually configure: error: source directory already configured; run "make distclean" there first and for the pkgbuild the error is always /mingw-w64-tools/src/mingw-w64-v10.0.0/mingw-w64-tools/gendef/configure: Permission denied. Could anyone help me with this? I have seen no one else online with the same problem.

Why are you using mingw on a linux installation? mingw is "minimal gnu for windows". Can't you build that using gcc?
Also, the "permission denied" is probably your configure script does not have the "executable" flag. You can set it with chmod +x configure.
Sorry it does not answer your main question, but I'm trying to figure out what you're trying to do.

I would recommend installing proton using the AUR
As non root user install the aur helper yay
git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/yay.git

cd yay

makepkg -si

After yay is installed you can just yay -S proton
Same goes for mingw-w64-tools yay -S mingw-w64-tools
